# Ziggy - Inertia js vue app NOT mounted AT ALL if we import route from 'ziggy' in app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am working on a projet where it uses Laravel , ziggy ,inertia and vue.
i can not use ziggy in vue as suggested by thier doc.
here is my complete app.js
NB i can see the expected Ziggy.js file in /js/ziggy.js

```
//___________app.js________________

require('./bootstrap')
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue'
import { App, plugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress/src'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import { mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'


import route from 'ziggy';// the vue app is not mounted at all if i import the route from 'ziggy' and there is no error in console.;
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: (name, params, absolute, config = Ziggy) => route(name, params, absolute, config),
    },
});
//Vue.config.productionTip = false
//Vue.mixin({ methods: { route: window.route } })
Vue.use(plugin)
Vue.use(PortalVue)
Vue.use(VueMeta)
InertiaProgress.init()

let app = document.getElementById('app')

new Vue({
    metaInfo: {
        titleTemplate: (title) => title ? `${title} - SSSYT` : 'your partner'
    },
    render: h => h(App, {
        props: {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: name =>
                import (`./Pages/${name}`).then(module => module.default),
        },
    }),
}).$mount(app)
```

and here  is the error i get in colnsole

````
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.inherits (app.js:124712)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:68991)
    at Object../node_modules/irc/lib/irc.js (app.js:69342)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Object../node_modules/ziggy/index.js (app.js:140181)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:141504)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Object.0 (app.js:142081)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

For `import route from 'ziggy';` to work, you need to alias `'ziggy'` to the correct location in your Mix file.

Add this to your `webpack.mix.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

// Mix v6
mix.alias({
    ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
});

// Or, for Mix v5
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
        },
    },
});
```

See [the section about this in the Ziggy docs](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy#advanced-setup) for more details.